# Use remove_action by accessing a class which was initiated under another class - PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, class, object

I have a situation like this in a WordPress plugin -

This is the parent class of the plugin -

```
class parent_class {
   public function __construct() {
      $this->initiate();
  }
   public static function init() {
        $instance = new parent_class ();
        return $instance;
  }

  public function initiate() {
        new child_class();
    }
}
```

Child class is defined in another file -

```
class child_class {
    public function __construct() {
       add_action( 'action_from_other_plugin', array( $this, 'function_i_want_to_remove' ), 32 );
    }
}
```

Now, my goal is to remove_action the action like this -

```
remove_action( 'action_from_other_plugin', array( child_class::init(), 'function_i_want_to_remove' ), 3200 );
```

Unfortunately it gives error that it is an undefined function. What am I missing in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add the class for a remove action. You can simply do:

```
remove_action( 'action_from_other_plugin', 'function_i_want_to_remove');
```

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately that did not worked in this case.

Comment: Strange. Where are you calling it from?